# NetBeans IDE 6.5 and Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, netbeans6.5

I would like to know if there is anyone who has used NetBeansIDE 6.5 before, also connected a MS Access 2007 database to a system developed with java Application option in the NetBeans platform. i would appreciate help very much especially if it's a tutorial send to me(alanzomo@yahoo.com)

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial on the Netbeans Website](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DemoOnJDBC_ODBC) shows how you can connect Netbeans to an ODBC data source using the JDBC-ODBC bridge.  This will work for Access databases.

Alternatively, you can use [this tool on the Sun website](http://developers.sun.com/product/jdbc/drivers) to find JDBC drivers for Microsoft Access.